# MongoDB On-Demand Materialized Views

Tags: mongodb, go

Does golang mongo driver support materialized views? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/materialized-views/

Comment: You answered your question then?

Comment: No, I found how to create views , but materialized views are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the question, though I suppose the answer to the question is "yes, the driver supports it". At the time of writing, ultimately everything in MongoDB is backed by a collection. Perhaps the additional context provided below will further clarify.

The key thing to note here is that there is currently no special "materialized view" object in MongoDB. There are:

- [Collections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/databases-and-collections/#collections)
- [Views](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/), which are effectively aggregation pipelines definitions for *collections* that are stored in the database and executed dynamically when queries against the view is executed.
- ["On-Demand Materialized Views"](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/materialized-views/), which is a technique for updating a *collection* using `$out` or `$merge`.

Regarding that last point, you can see reference to this directly on [the linked page], for example:

> The `$merge` stage writes the output to the `monthlybakesales` collection.

So there is nothing special here for the driver to support. The driver will be interacting with a collection which is supported.

Comment: Yes, what you said is correct. I understood it when went through the documentation again and tried creating views and materialised views from my go code. Thank you so much for the answer. that is definitely helpful

Comment: Have one more query, I used materialized views with $merge for combining 2 collections. How to handle when the records in either of those collections get deleted but your output collection still holds those records. Could you please help?

Comment: Sounds more appropriate for a new question instead of a comment on an answered one. My best guess is that you'd need to introduce some 'soft delete' mechanism (eg a boolean flag) that gets materialized and then perhaps introduce some TTL index. Other solutions using change streams to monitor and 'replicate' deletions more directly might be a bit complex